# Problem with form buttons in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button

I have buttons on a page that look like:

```
<p>
    <a href="view.php">
      <input type="button" name="view" value="View Database" />
    </a>
</p>
```

IE does not support these buttons or multiple buttons I am not sure which one. Does anyone know how to fix this to work with IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?  If you want a custom button to redirect to `view.php`, you can use `onclick:`

```
<input type="button" name="view" value="View Database" onclick="window.location.href='view.php';" />
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Embedding a button within an `<a>` tag is not normally done, and really doesn't make any sense. If you want your link to look like a button, then just use the `<input>` tag with some script on the onclick event, or use css to make your link look button-ish (start by using display:block or display:inline-block);

Answer (score 3):

You can't put an input into the  tag, instead, you can create a form, and change your button to a submit one. Then you can choose the target url in the form, like this:

```
<form action="view.php">

    <input type="submit" name="view" value="View Database" />

</form>
```

I would recommend this over using javascript, because buttons are not designed for navigating a site. If you want to submit information, which is what they are used for, you won't be able to do it so cleanly using javascript.

Comment: +1 good solution, I never thought of using a small form for this.  I would however add `method="GET"` to the `<form>` tag - the target page may behave strangely with a POST when theoretically it's only viewing it to begin with.

Comment: @Andy, `GET` is the default method for a form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" 
onclick="javascript:document.location='view.php';" 
value="View Database"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this ugly monster:

```
<input  type="button" name="view" value="View Database" onclick="javascript:window.location='view.php'"/>
```

Comment: Why do you have a label called 'javascript' in there? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Uhm, what does your link mean?Javascript is not mandatory, you are right.